# list of figures for a single chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I want a list of figures for a single chapter (appendix a).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Front}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic1}\caption{Picture 1}\label{fig:pic1}
\end{figure}


\mainmatter
\chapter{Main}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic2}\caption{Picture 2}\label{fig:pic2}
\end{figure}


\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}

\listoffigures % only Pictures 3 to 6 should be listet %

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic3}\caption{Picture 3}\label{fig:pic3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic4}\caption{Picture 4}\label{fig:pic4}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic5}\caption{Picture 5}\label{fig:pic5}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic6}\caption{Picture 6}\label{fig:pic6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Pictures 5 and 6}\label{fig:pics5-6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So you don't want a global `\listoffigures`?

Comment: no, not in this instance

Comment: @marina you can use `minitoc` package ...

Comment: @juanuni: The `minitoc` package is basically unmaintained for years now. `etoc` seems to be its successor, however, by another author, who is also a user here (jfbu)

Comment: `minitoc` pagacke is obsolete?

Comment: @juanuni: Not obsolete, but not 'future-proof' ;-)

Comment: @juanuni: I had a look into the `etoc` documentation. I am not sure that `etoc` is suitable for this as it seems to treat `toc` only, not `lof` etc

Comment: Yeah, i'm searching about that. Anyway, with `minitoc` package is easy to solve this question, if not obsolete yet, works :v ...

Comment: @juanuni: thanks, `minitoc` works like a charm

Comment: @marina you are welcome ...

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the `\listoffigures` to have `\iffalse` at the start and `\fi` at the moment the appendix starts, so the items before the appendix will not show.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo just for the example

\setuptoc{lof}{leveldown}
\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\iffalse}}
\newcommand{\appendixmore}{\cleardoublepage\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\fi}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\chapter{Front}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic1}\caption{Picture 1}\label{fig:pic1}
\end{figure}


\mainmatter
\chapter{Main}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic2}\caption{Picture 2}\label{fig:pic2}
\end{figure}


\appendix
\chapter{Appendix A}


\listoffigures % only Pictures 3 to 6 should be listet %

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic3}\caption{Picture 3}\label{fig:pic3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\includegraphics{pic4}\caption{Picture 4}\label{fig:pic4}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic5}\caption{Picture 5}\label{fig:pic5}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{pic6}\caption{Picture 6}\label{fig:pic6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Pictures 5 and 6}\label{fig:pics5-6}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]